# spark streaming: Perform a daily aggregation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a streaming dataframe and I want to calculate some daily counters.
So far, I have been using tumbling windows with watermark as follows:

```
.withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes") \
.groupBy(window("timestamp","1 day")) \
.count()
```

My question is whether this is the best way (resource wise) to do this daily aggregation, or whether I should instead perform a series of aggregations on smaller windows (say hourly or even less) and then aggregate these hourly counters to achieve the daily count.

Moreover, if I try the second approach, meaning the smaller windows, how can I do this?

I can not perform both aggregations (the hourly and daily) within the same spark streaming application, I keep getting the following:

```
Multiple streaming aggregations are not supported with streaming
DataFrames/Datasets.
```

Should I therefore use a spark application to post the hourly aggregations to a Kafka topic, read this stream from another spark application and perform the daily sum up?

If yes, then how should I go about the "update" outputmode in the producer? The second application will be getting the updated values from the first application and therefore this "sum up" will be wrong. 
Moreover, adding any `trigger` will also not work with the watermark, since any late events arriving will cause a previous counter update and I would be running into the same problem again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should perform aggregation on the most shortest time span required and then perform secondary aggregation on those primary aggs. Performing a agg for `1 day` would OOM your job if not now then definitely in future.

1. Perform primary aggreagtions count hourly or 5 minute count and record them in a Time serries DB like Prometheus / Graphite.
2. Use grafana to plot those metrics, perform secondary aggregations like daily count on top of primary aggregation.

This would increase some DevOps efforts but it is but you could visually monitor your application in real-time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree with you but as you said this would require additional effort and additional software as well. Assuming we can only go with spark for now, how should I define the second aggregation layer from the "update" Kafka output sink? Summin up the smaller windows does not work exactly due to the update output Mode.

Comment: Then relaying the counts periodically into new Kafka Topic and reading back into new Spark job is only option you are left with.

Raw events topic -> Spark Stream (1st Agg)  -> 1st agg topic -> Spark Stream (2nd Agg) and so on

Comment: Thanks a lot. To that end, if the output sink is set to 'update', I would be getting constnatly updating counters, meaning that any 'sum up' operation on the second Agg spark stream will not work. Same with 'complete' output mode. Do you have any ideas as to how to handle this? Thanks in advance.